# coverage per test with gradle using jacoco offline instrumentation - java.lang.IllegalStateException: JaCoCo agent not started

Tags: java, gradle, classloader, jacoco, instrumentation

I am trying to do a coverage per test using gradle+jacoco.

Idea is to have an implementation of `org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener`, and reset session-id at regular events (test start and test end) and dump coverage.

(Entire project to demo the problem is at https://github.com/jayanmn/gradle-coverage-per-test-debug/tree/main )

Instrumentation is done via jacoco-offline instrumentation using ant tasks inside gradle. (offline as the testing environment includes some tests - somewhat integration type ).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.8.5', classifier: 'runtime'
        classpath group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.core', version: '0.8.5'
    }
}
```

The dependency section is like below

```
    dependencies {
    //offline instrument via ant task
    jacocoAnt group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.ant', version: '0.8.5', classifier: 'nodeps'

    //the jacoco runtime private for RT.getAgent()
    jacocoRuntime group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.8.5', classifier: 'runtime'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Running of test (sampletest)

```
task sampletest(type: Test) {
    ignoreFailures = true
    //jars used every step is same.
    println classpath.asPath

    forkEvery 1
    maxParallelForks 1

    doFirst {
        println "org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT loaded from " + RT.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()

        systemProperty 'jacoco-agent.destfile', buildDir.path + '/jacoco/firsttests.exec'
        classpath = files(instrument.outputDir) + classpath + configurations.jacocoRuntime

    }
    beforeTest { TestDescriptor descriptor ->
        println "org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT loaded from " + RT.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
    }

    afterTest { TestDescriptor descriptor ->
        //get agent will fail with Agent not started.
        systemProperty 'jacoco-agent.destfile', buildDir.path + '/jacoco/aftertests.exec'

        //agent not started error
        def agent = RT.getAgent()
        agent.sessionId = descriptor.name
        agent.dump(true)

    }
}
```

For some reason

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: JaCoCo agent not started.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sampletest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JaCoCo agent not started.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.Agent.getInstance(Agent.java:77)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT.getAgent(RT.java:33)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT$getAgent.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_q0s35v9r0an7s8a7ayxelgpr$_run_closure6$_closure13.doCall(C:\repos\number-utils\build.gradle:91)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:41)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.afterTest(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.TestListenerAdapter.completed(TestListenerAdapter.java:50)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.completed(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
```

Problem is likely to be with classloaders  of "buildscript" and test block?  What is the correct way to add jacoco-agent-runtime ?

Comment: Bounty comment : Just looking for answers. I just accepted the default message, hence the 'reputable source' part came.

Comment: as far as i know, you need to add the -javaagent:.../org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar argument starting the jvm

Comment: I thought that is needed only for on-the-fly instrumentation. Once instrumentation is done, agent is needed as runtime not as java agent. Will try anyway :)

Comment: That is not needed: https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html#:~:text=In%20offline%20mode%20the%20JaCoCo,class%20files%20are%20already%20instrumented.&text=exec%20file%20can%20be%20configured,system%20property%20%22%20jacoco%2Dagent.

Comment: I just read your error message and it says, that the agent is not started. So might be you explicit call, to  org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT.getAgent(RT.java:33) is the problem than. the agent is the java agent you dont have here. to dump the files than is already instrumente in the code and dumped on jvm shutdown hook

Comment: JaCoCo has some different way to package tool.  https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/org.jacoco.agent.rt/src/org/jacoco/agent/rt/RT.java .  The  agent is actually working fine as I get normal data collected. (the exec file).   Trouble is call that happens from TestListener context.

Answer (score 1):

`afterTest` `org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener` is executed by Gradle in the VM for Gradle, but not in the VM for tests with JaCoCo.

For the proof:

for `src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`

```
public class ExampleTest {
  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println(java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());
  }
}
```

and `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
  id "java"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    afterTest {
        System.println(java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName())
    }
}
```

execution of command `gradle build` will produce something like

```
> Task :test

ExampleTest > test STANDARD_OUT
    33542@Godin.local
33018@Godin.local
```

two numbers `33542` and `33018` are IDs of Java processes, and as you can see they are different.

---

`org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT` can be used to communicate only with JaCoCo running in the same VM.

To communicate with JaCoCo in another VM you can use agent `output` modes `tcpclient` and `tcpserver`, or via JMX using agent option `jmx=true` - see https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html And the same options available for the case of offline instrumentation - see https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html

---

> Idea is to have an implementation of org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener, and reset session-id at regular events (test start and test end) and dump coverage.

JUnit 4 has `org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener` which is executed inside VM for tests by JUnit, an example of its implementation similar to your idea can be found at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/5.14.0.18788/sonar-jacoco-listeners/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/jacoco/JUnitListener.java

Unfortunately according to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1330
seems that as of today there is no easy way in Gradle to configure JUnit 4 to use  `org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener`, however seems possible to configure JUnit 5 to use its `org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener`.

Comment: Oh! Did not notice that listener and test was different processes.  Will try the network/jmx approach you mentioned.

Comment: For anyone trying out this solution: Using jmx does expose Runtime,  but the JVM does not exist when afterTest runs!  Need more work.

Comment: @Jayan personally I think that `org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener` will be a better option than Gradle's `afterTest` ;)

Answer (score -1):

You also need thejacoco agent initialize plugin. Here's the maven example, but I am sure there must be something similar for gradle:

```
   <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${basedir}\target\jacoco.exec</destFile>
                                <propertyName>argLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${basedir}\target\jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}\target</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```